# Adding a character to the start and end of each line a txt file file php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a file called list.txt and I want to put the letter 'a' in front and the letter 'b' in the back of each line in the list.

Comment: regex seems like the wrong technology here - way overkill

Answer (score 5):

in php

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$fixedFileContents = preg_replace('/.+/', 'a$0b', $fileContents);
file_put_contents($fixedFileContents, 'list.txt');
```

Comment: Why would I get a down vote? Its not a useful answer?

Comment: i dunno, your answer works to.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   $text = file_get_contents('./list.txt');
    $array = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach($array as $ar)
    {
    $new_text .= 'a'.$ar."b\n";
    }
    file_put_contents('./list.txt', $new_text);
?>
```

Comment: if the file is huge you'll run out of memory with this.  If doing this in php, I'd read from a file, output to a second file, then overwrite the original file when completely done.

Comment: +1 for doing the homework of the asker